# How can you turn this hover function off?

Tags: css, checkbox, hover

My checkbox has box-shadow..when I hover on the checkbox.
I tried turning it off in every way but still couldn't turn it off.
It doesn't show on the inspect.
box-shadow and background color doesn't seem to work.
This is my checkbox.
It has weird blue shadow around the border... [Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9okGs.png)

The checbox form is in this format.

```
.treejs .treejs-node__checked > .treejs-checkbox:before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: #D9368D;
    border-color: hsl(328, 68%, 53%);
    box-shadow: hsl(328, 68%, 53%) inset;
}
```

Can anyone please help how to turn it off?

Comment: How you tried removing outline?

Comment: Yeah it hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try box-shadow:none , it will work